# Dump HDF4 arrays to ascii with full precision of the source file

Tags: java, python, hdf5

I have a number of HDF4 files with 3D arrays that I would like to dump to ascii with the float values reflecting the full precision of the source file. I've used HDP:  `HDP dumpsds` but it only prints 6 digits of precision and rounds up. My preference would be an open source utility made to read HDF4; python or java? thanks. (I used the tag HDF5, there is no HDF4. I realize these are not compatible formats but the development communities often work in parallel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed or do install [pyhdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pysclint/files/pyhdf/) then you can easily get full-precision access in python:

```
from numpy import *
from pyhdf.SD import SD
sd = SD('data.hdf', SDC.READ)
sd.datasets()
```

Assuming they were stored as 32-bit floats in the HDF4 files, then you can print the values with as much precision as you desire:

```
image = sd.datasets.select('3d_image_name')
print "%.23f" % (image[2][2][2],)
```

which will print the float at (x,y,z) = (2,2,2) to 23 decimal places.